# What macros are defined in a Web2c format file?

Tags: latex, tex

Web2c defines its format style using Pascal strings, so there are no separator characters between csnames.  Is there a straightforward way of listing all csnames bound in a .fmt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arthur Reutenauer [answered this question on tex.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323/what-macros-are-defined-in-a-web2c-format-file/797#797) when I asked it there.

The Web2c implementation of Tex has an undocumented command-line switch `-debug-format`, which dumps lots of information about the format it would compile with to stdout.